# Refresh Desktop using xdotool

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-16.04, xdotool

Hi I am trying to refresh my Desktop, simulate "F5"/"ctrl+R" key pressing using xdotool.

I have tried to `xdotool key F5` but I got

```
^[[15~jake@jake-PC ~ $ ~
```

and after pressing Enter:

```
bash: /home/jake: Is a directory
```

Then I have tried

```
xdotool search --classname Desktop
73400321
```

Got that id, then tried:

```
xdotool search --classname Desktop key F5
xdotool search --classname Desktop key ctrl+R
```

it didn't refresh my page.

Question: what can I do to refresh my desktop? By the way I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Thank you

Comment: What desktop environment do you use? unity, gnome, kde, ... ?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on http://unix.stackexchange.com  OR http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Not xdotool but `xrefresh` may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call with sync:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --classname Desktop windowactivate --sync key F5
```

also you can try xdotool script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdotool
keydown Ctrl
keydown super
sleep 0.1
key D
keyup Ctrl
keyup super
key F5
```

Another alternative you can use exec function on xdotool to call show desktop script (or create it)